# How to implement a Monte Carlo Simulation for studying uncertainty in dynamic stiffness?

Tags: dynamics, simulation, stiffness

I have a dynamic mechanical system of the form:
$$\mathbf{M{\ddot q}+{\Omega_c}G{\dot q}+{Kq}=F(t)}$$

and I need to introduce some uncertainty for the $K$ parameter, which is a symetric matrix of $q$ degrees of freedom.

I did a bit of research of Monte Carlo simulation but I´m a bit confused of how different textbooks approach the problem.

For example , my actual stiffness value is of $1e8$, and I wish to generate values uniformly distributed between $K_l = 1e6$ and $K_u = 1e12$.

I found that I can do this by applying:
$$\lambda_i = \mu_{\lambda_i} + \epsilon_i$$
where $\mu_{\lambda_i}$ is the mean value of $\lambda_i$ and $\epsilon$ is a random parameter, and also 
$$\sigma_{\lambda_i}^2 = E[{(\lambda_i-\mu_{\lambda_i})^2}]$$

I would be using Matlab for running the simulation , with the command `rand` I can generate a randomly distributed numbers between 0 and 1.

The problem I find with this is that I don't know know to input the boundaries of the $K$ stiffnes values I want.

Then I found another text book that explains how to generate random variables using:
$$ X_i = A + (B-A)R_i$$
Where $R_i$ is the random number which can be generated by Matlab with rand command to generate a new random variable $X_i$, with lower and upper limits $A$ and $B$. So in matlab I would do a for loop like this:

```
for i=1:num
    Ki=Kl+(Ku-Kl)*rand;
end
```

My main question would actually be, what is the difference between these two methods and for the first one, would $\epsilon$ just be a random 0-1 number adding to the average designated value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to forget about the mathematical theory and start thinking about what the engineering means. It's hard to think of any situation where the stiffness of a sensibly designed structure might vary "randomly" by a factor of a million, unless all the stiffness values are so high that the response is very insensitive to the stiffness value - and in that case, why bother doing a simulation at all?

Changing the stiffness of a dynamic system by a factor of 1 million will change the frequency of the fundamental modes by a factor of about 1 thousand. That isn't "a design" in any sense of the words that I can recognise in real life engineering.

Think about what *causes* your stiffness to change - geometrical tolerances, unknown material properties, poorly controlled nonlinear behaviour (e.g. buckling, plasticity, creep), etc. Then use those *physical* parameters to *calculate* the stiffness for each simulation point in your Monte Carlo study.

Note that this approach will change the different entries in the $q$-degrees of freedom stiffness matrix by *different* amounts, and that is probably much more realistic than multiplying the whole matrix by one scalar factor.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @alephzero. Actually you are totally right and I made a stupid mistake by saying that my interval was by a factor of 1 million. From what I read for this situation the variation coefficient should be within the range of 15% - 40% of the mean designated value. Even so, what you say about thinking in engineering terms also made me think more clearly.

Comment: I wouldn't have questioned a "tolerance band" of -50% to +100% or even -80% to +400% in real life, But a million was definitely too much!